# JPA OneToOne clarifications

Tags: hibernate, orm, jpa, jpa-2.0

I was reading [this](http://www.apress.com/book/view/9781430219545) book. Explaing about "@OneToOne unidirectional", the author has taken the following `Customer`, `Address` example:

```
@Entity
public class Customer{
   @Id @GeneratedValue
   private Long id;
   private String name;
   private Address address;
   //few other columns, getters/setters
}

@Entity
public class Address{
   @Id @GeneratedValue
   private Long id;
   private String city;
   //few other columns, getters/setters

}
```

And was saying that -

- This is the minimum required
  annotaions.
- No @OneToOne annotaion is
  needed.(Because, by default, the
  persistance provider will assume it)
- The @JoinColumn annotation allows you
  to customize the mapping of a foreign
  key. As show below, we can RENAME the
  foreign key column to ADD_FK

And then about this one:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {    
    @Id    @GeneratedValue    
    private Long id;      
    private String name;    
    @OneToOne       
    @JoinColumn(name="ADD_FK")    
    private Address address;    
    //few other    columns, getters/setters 
}

@Entity
public class Order {   
    ....       
    List<OrderLine> orderLines;   
    ... 
}
```

- By default, OneToMany relationship is
  assumend when the collection of an
  entity type is being used.

My questions:

1. Are the above statements Valid? Because when I try these examples on Hibernate, I was getting exceptions.
2. Does the statements are made as per the JPA
   standards?
3. Or is it that Hibernate is
   implemented differently?

Kindly clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my knowledge, relations between entities must be *explicitly* mapped. From the JPA 1.0 specification (bold is mine):

> #### 2.1.7 Entity Relationships
>
> Relationships among entities may be
>   one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-one,
>   or many-to-many. Relationships are
>   polymorphic.
>
> If there is an association between two
>   entities, one of the following
>   relationship modeling annotations
>   **must be** applied to the corresponding persistent property or
>   field of the referencing entity:
>   `OneToOne`, `OneToMany`, `ManyToOne`,
>   `ManyToMany`. For associations that do
>   not specify the target type (e.g.,
>   where Java generic types are not used
>   for collections), it is necessary to
>   specify the entity that is the target
>   of the relationship.
>
> (...)

And this didn't change in JPA 2.0.

I thus annotate relationships between entities. And AFAIK, Hibernate will indeed complain about not being able to persist a complex type when not doing so.

But unless someone can show me the relevant part of the spec, I consider the behavior as correct.

#### References

- JPA 1.0 specification

  - Section 2.1.7 "Entity Relationships"
- JPA 2.0 specification

  - Section 2.9 "Entity Relationships"